# Could someone explain what this error about?

Tags: encryption, networking

> Test connection ([Triatin_SALESBANK_SFTP_Receive_Triatin], [SFTP Receive]) failed with message:
>   Unable to logon[user: ****] into target server [***********:22] via SOCKS proxy [172.22.144.141:5,002] because of error: Failed to negotiate a transport component [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1] [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1] [Unknown cause]

EDIT after Mike's post:

Client asking us to change to SHA1 . We don't have an option now. I tried using Filezilla and Cerberus. But I didn't get any option to change to SHA1. Could you please help me regarding this issue?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include what you are doing when the error appears? I'm sure some people can figure it out from the error itself, but it doesnt hurt to be more explicit about it. A more informative title would also be good. Thank you!

Comment: This is not a security question. At best, this is a question for your bank's support line.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to diagnose for sure without knowing which FTP client and server software you're using, and seeing the logs from both sides, but I can take a guess.

In SSL/TLS, a client has to "negotiate" with the server which encryption cipher it will use to encrypt the session. Both the client and the server have a list of ciphers they support, and they "negotiate" to settle on one that they both support. I'm guessing that's what this means:

> Failed to negotiate a transport component

I'm guessing the first list of ciphers are the ones the client wanted to use:

> [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]

and the second are the ones the server wanted to use:

> [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]

Note that there are no ciphers that are common between the two lists.

**In a nutshell**: your client is configured to use the old hash `sha1`, while the server has been updated to only accept the newer `sha2/sha256`. The solution is to change the SSL/TLS configuration on your client to use one of the newer `sha2/sha256` ciphers.

Comment: I've never configured SSL/TLS on an FTP client, so I'm not sure. There must be documentation online for how to change the SSL/TLS settings.

Answer (score 1):

If I read correctly your log, the client try to do a SFTP connection but not a FTPS.

> Test connection ([Triatin_SALESBANK_**SFTP**_Receive_Triatin], [SFTP
>   Receive]) failed with message: Unable to logon[user: ****] into target
>   server [***********:**22**]

SFTP is not FTP tunneled in SSH, but a distinct file transfer protocol which is part of the SSH suite.

On the other hand, FTP with SSL/TLS is FTPS.

If you want to correct the negotiation between the client and the server, you must specify to use the sames ciphers on them.

Of course, SHA-2 if preferred as SHA-1, but if you want to modify the ciphers on your server, you must look around the SSH process.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, had to downgrade libssl on the client system because upgrading of libssl on the server system wasnt possible (IP camera - end-of-life).

Because of security the downgrade is not advised, we 'ensured' security by placing the devices in a separate network (VLAN).